# VBA excel search multiple columns

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to search through multiple columns  for a particular value. The code I have below is only searching column D. Whenever I alter it I get an error. I want to search columns `D to M`. Thanks

```
Do While (Range("D" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value) > 0

 'If value in column D = LSearchValue, copy entire row to Sheet2
 If Range("D" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value = LSearchValue Then

   'Select row in Sheet1 to copy
   Rows(CStr(LSearchRow) & ":" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Select
   Selection.Copy

   'Paste row into Sheet2 in next row
   Sheets("Sheet2").Select
   Rows(CStr(LCopyToRow) & ":" & CStr(LCopyToRow)).Select
   ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial

   'Move counter to next row
   LCopyToRow = LCopyToRow + 1

   'Go back to Sheet1 to continue searching
   Sheets("Sheet1").Select

 End If

 LSearchRow = LSearchRow + 1

Loop
```

Comment: Do you expect multiple or single matches when searching columns D through M?

Comment: Single matches.  So if a user searches for an account number the macro will search the each column from d:m . And copy each each row where that account number is found into sheet 2.

Answer (score 0):

I redid your code in the following way, I hope you will find it helpful.

```
Sub searchValue()

Dim LSearchValue As String
Dim LSearchRow As Integer
Dim LCopyToRow As Integer
Dim iColumn As Integer

'I'm looking for string = "5", change it to your value or pass it through procedure parameter
LSearchValue = "5"

LCopyToRow = 1

For iColumn = 4 To 13
    LSearchRow = 1
    While Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(LSearchRow, iColumn).Value > 0
        If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(LSearchRow, iColumn).Value = LSearchValue Then
            'Select row in Sheet1 to copy
            Rows(LSearchRow).Select
            Selection.Copy

            'Paste row into Sheet2 in next row
            Sheets("Sheet2").Select
            Rows(LCopyToRow).Select
            ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial

            'Move counter to next row
            LCopyToRow = LCopyToRow + 1

            'Go back to Sheet1 to continue searching
            Sheets("Sheet1").Select
        End If
        LSearchRow = LSearchRow + 1
    Wend
Next iColumn

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This might get you started.

```
Sub FindValues()
    Dim rw As Integer, cl As Range, LSearchValue As Long, LCopyToRow As Integer

    LCopyToRow = 1
    LSearchValue = 10

    For rw = 1 To 100

        For Each cl In Range("D" & rw & ":M" & rw)
            If cl = LSearchValue Then
                cl.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Rows(LCopyToRow & ":" & LCopyToRow)
                LCopyToRow = LCopyToRow + 1
            End If
        Next cl

    Next rw
End Sub
```

Note:

1. Not sure how you are defining your `LSearchValue` value. Here I do it explicitly.
2. Here I am looping over 100 rows (D1:D100). You can change to suit.
3. If you need to check that a value is greater than 0 upfront (as in your original code) then add in an `If...` statement

Comment: This is the same issue as the below  Do While (Range("D" & LsearchRow)) > 0 . This line of code works when it is -1 , and generates the same errors as below.

Comment: What purpose is the Loop serving? Suppose `Range("D" & LsearchRow)` evaluates to `10`. This means you will get an infinite loop as it always > 0. There is no way to exit the loop. Where does `lSearchRow` get defined?

Comment: The objective of the code was to loop through the rows. from the first row to the last row in sheet1. However the information to be obtained lays between column D:M. (ie that  when the account being searched for is found it copies that row and pastes it into sheet 2). The objective of the loop was this to continue until all rows have been searched . unless i have approached this in the  wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub searchValue()
  Dim LSearchValue As String`
  Dim LSearchRow As Integer
  Dim LCopyToRow As Integer
  Dim iColumn As Integer

  Sheet2.Cells.Clear
  Sheet1.Select

  On Error GoTo Err_Execute

  'user inputs value to be found
  LSearchValue = InputBox("Please enter a value to search for.", "Enter value")
  LCopyToRow = 1

  For iColumn = 4 To 13
    LSearchRow = 1
    While Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(LSearchRow, iColumn).Value > -1
      If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(LSearchRow, iColumn).Value = LSearchValue Then
        'Select row in Sheet1 to copy
        Rows(LSearchRow).Select
        Selection.Copy

        'Paste row into Sheet2 in next row
        Sheets("Sheet2").Select

        Rows(CStr(LCopyToRow) & ":" & CStr(LCopyToRow)).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste

        'Move counter to next row
        LCopyToRow = LCopyToRow + 1

        'Go back to Sheet1 to continue searching
        Sheets("Sheet1").Select
      End If

      LSearchRow = LSearchRow + 1
    Wend
  Next iColumn

  'Position on cell A3
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
  Range("A3").Select

  MsgBox "All matching data has been copied."
  Exit Sub

Err_Execute:
   MsgBox "An error occurred."
End Sub
```

I have tried to implement the above codes. All the codes I have experienced two issues.

1. `While Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(LSearchRow, iColumn).Value > -1` works instead of `0`.
   the data will be copied over but an error occurs because duplicates are being pasted.
2. When I debug, an error is occurring on this line of code `LSearchRow = LSearchRow + 1`

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment so I'm adding this as an answer.

> While Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(LSearchRow, iColumn).Value > -1 works
>   instead of 0. the data will be copied over but an error occurs because
>   duplicates are being pasted.

It's not working really. `Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(LSearchRow, iColumn).Value > -1` is returning true for all your rows, that is why you are getting error on line `LSearchRow = LSearchRow + 1` (actually it is 'overflow' error).

I don't know why you're doing such condition. If this if for empty cells try `Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(LSearchRow, iColumn).Value <> ""` instead?

Or instead of While ... Wend you can do something like this:

```
Dim i as Long

For i=1 to Sheet("Sheet1").Cells(1,iColumn).End(xlDown).Row 'looping from first cell in column 'iColumn' to last not empty cell
    ...
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub FindValues()
   Dim LSearchRow As Integer
   Dim rw As Integer, cl As Range, LSearchValue As Long, LCopyToRow As Integer

   Sheet2.Cells.Clear
   Sheet1.Select

   'On Error GoTo Err_Execute
   'this for the end user to input the required A/C to be searched
    LSearchValue = InputBox("Please enter a value to search for.", "Enter value")
    LCopyToRow = 2

    For rw = 1 To 1555
        For Each cl In Range("D" & rw & ":M" & rw)
            If cl = LSearchValue Then
                cl.EntireRow.Copy

                'Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2")
                '.Rows(LCopyToRow & ":" & LCopyToRow)

                Sheets("Sheet2").Select
                Rows(LCopyToRow & ":" & LCopyToRow).Select

                'Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
                Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
                    xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

                'Move counter to next row
                LCopyToRow = LCopyToRow + 1

                'Go back to Sheet1 to continue searching
                Sheets("Sheet1").Select
            End If

            'LSearchRow = LSearchRow + 1 
        Next cl
    Next rw

    'Position on cell A3
    'Application.CutCopyMode = False
    'Selection.Copy

    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Cells.Select

    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
       SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Sheet2.Select

    MsgBox "All matching data has been copied."
    Exit Sub

'Err_Execute:
   MsgBox "An error occurred."

End Sub
```

Comment: I finally came up with this. Which works perfectly. Thank you all very much. Just moving onto the next part,. Thank you all so much. :)

Answer (score 0):

Using the `Find()` method will be the most efficient method of finding matching values.

```
Sub Find_Value()
Dim lFirstMatch As Long
Dim rngSearch As Range
Dim rngNextRow As Range
Dim sSearchValue As String

    'Set the Search Value
    sSearchValue = "Something"

    'Find the Search Value
    Set rngSearch = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D:M").Find(What:=sSearchValue, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows)
    If Not rngSearch Is Nothing Then

        'If found preserve the first row
        lFirstMatch = rngSearch.Row
        Do

            'Find the last used row on Sheet2
            Set rngNextRow = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
            If Not rngNextRow Is Nothing Then

                'If a last used row is found, copy the row from Sheet1 to the next available row on Sheet2
                rngSearch.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=rngNextRow.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow
            Else

                'If a last used row is not found, copy the row from Sheet1 to the first row on Sheet2
                rngSearch.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Rows(1)
            End If

            'Find the next value on Sheet1
            Set rngSearch = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D:M").Find(What:=sSearchValue, LookAt:=xlWhole, After:=rngSearch, SearchOrder:=xlByRows)

        'Stop looking for the Search Value once you have come full circle back to the first value
        Loop While Not rngSearch.Row = lFirstMatch
    End If

End Sub
```